# Pyparsing Precedence breaks with Unary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to implement a subset of Python's operators for arithmetic parsing using `pyparsing`. I have the following code implementing my parser:

```py
variable_names = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Literal('$') + pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + '_'))
integer = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums)
double = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums) + '.' + pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums))
parser = pyparsing.operatorPrecedence(variable_names | double | integer, [
                                ('**', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                                ('-', 1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                                (pyparsing.oneOf('* / // %'), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                                (pyparsing.oneOf('+ -'), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                                (pyparsing.oneOf('> >= < <= == !='), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                                ('not', 1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                                ('and', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                                ('or', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT)])
```

For the most part, this works fine, although sometimes it breaks when I use the unary `-`. Specifically, I think (I may be wrong) it breaks if I use `-` after higher precedence operands, which in this case is just `**`. The following examples show the issue:

```
parsing 5 * 10 * -2             yields: ['5', '*', '10', '*', ['-', '2']]
parsing 5 * 10 ** -2            yields: ['5', '*', '10']               # Wrong
parsing 5 * 10 ** (-2)          yields: ['5', '*', ['10', '**', ['-', '2']]]
parsing 5 and not 8             yields: ['5', 'and', ['not', '8']]
parsing 5 and - 8               yields: ['5', 'and', ['-', '8']]
```

Is there any reason why this is happening? What am I missing?

Comment: what if you define `-` as higher then `**` ?

Comment: Great start! I've found that things parse better if you make exponentiation LEFT associative in the parser, but just take care to evaluate right-to-left for proper mathematical evaluation. Also, consider using the numeric expressions defined in pyparsing_common, for integer and real especially - these also do parse-time conversion to give you actual values, and not just the strings. Also, is `$000` a legit variable name? You might need to tighten up `variable_names` - look into the 2-argument version of `Word` to make sure your var name does not start with a digit (and why plural for this?).

Comment: @PaulMcG You're correct about all of it, I am changing it now to fix the variable names and use the commons for the integer and float values. Only thing that had no effect for me is changing the variable associativity to LEFT, no change, still fails to parse the example correctly.

Comment: Looks like @furas has provided a good answer. Another tip: use `parser.runTests()` passing a multi-line quoted string of test cases. Each will be echoed with either the parsed results or an exception indicating where the exception occurred.

Comment: I didn't realize you were the author of pyparsing :) Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me you should define `-` as higher then `**`

```
('-', 1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
('**', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
```

and this should resolve your problem.

---

Minimal working code

```
import pyparsing

variable_names = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Literal('$') + pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + '_'))

integer = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums)

double = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums) + '.' + pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums))

parser = pyparsing.operatorPrecedence(
            variable_names | double | integer,
            [
                ('-',  1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                ('**', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                (pyparsing.oneOf('* / // %'), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                (pyparsing.oneOf('+ -'), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                (pyparsing.oneOf('> >= < <= == !='), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                ('not', 1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                ('and', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                ('or',  2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT)
            ]
        )

examples = [
    "5 * 10 ** -2",
    "5 * 10 * -2",
    "5 * 10 ** (-2)",
    "5 * -10 ** 2",
    "5 * (-10) ** 2",    
    "5 and not 8",
    "5 and -8",
    "1 ** -2",
    "-1 ** 2",
]

longest = max(map(len, examples))

for ex in examples:
    result = parser.parseString(ex)
    print(f'{ex:{longest}}  <=>  {result}')
```

Results:

```
5 * 10 ** -2    <=>  [['5', '*', ['10', '**', ['-', '2']]]]
5 * 10 * -2     <=>  [['5', '*', '10', '*', ['-', '2']]]
5 * 10 ** (-2)  <=>  [['5', '*', ['10', '**', ['-', '2']]]]
5 * -10 ** 2    <=>  [['5', '*', [['-', '10'], '**', '2']]]
5 * (-10) ** 2  <=>  [['5', '*', [['-', '10'], '**', '2']]]
5 and not 8     <=>  [['5', 'and', ['not', '8']]]
5 and -8        <=>  [['5', 'and', ['-', '8']]]
1 ** -2         <=>  [['1', '**', ['-', '2']]]
-1 ** 2         <=>  [[['-', '1'], '**', '2']]
```

---

**BTW:** for comparision: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and [Python - Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

---

**EDIT:**

I can get `-500` for `5 * -10 ** 2` (`[[5, '*', ['-', [10, '**', 2]]]]`) when I keep `**` before `-` but I use

```
integer = pyparsing.pyparsing_common.signed_integer
```

---

```
import pyparsing

variable_names = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Literal('$') + pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums + '_'))

#integer = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums)
integer = pyparsing.pyparsing_common.signed_integer

double = pyparsing.Combine(pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums) + '.' + pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums))

parser = pyparsing.operatorPrecedence(
            variable_names | double | integer,
            [
                ('**', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                ('-',  1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                (pyparsing.oneOf('* / // %'), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                (pyparsing.oneOf('+ -'), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                (pyparsing.oneOf('> >= < <= == !='), 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                ('not', 1, pyparsing.opAssoc.RIGHT),
                ('and', 2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT),
                ('or',  2, pyparsing.opAssoc.LEFT)
            ]
        )

examples = [
    "5 * 10 ** -2",
    "5 * 10 * -2",
    "5 * 10 ** (-2)",
    "5 * -10 ** 2",
    "5 * (-10) ** 2",    
    "5 and not 8",
    "5 and -8",
    "1 ** -2",
    "-1 ** 2",
]

longest = max(map(len, examples))

for ex in examples:
    result = parser.parseString(ex)
    print(f'{ex:{longest}}  <=>  {result}')
```

Result:

```
5 * 10 ** -2    <=>  [[5, '*', [10, '**', -2]]]
5 * 10 * -2     <=>  [[5, '*', 10, '*', ['-', 2]]]
5 * 10 ** (-2)  <=>  [[5, '*', [10, '**', ['-', 2]]]]
5 * -10 ** 2    <=>  [[5, '*', ['-', [10, '**', 2]]]]
5 * (-10) ** 2  <=>  [[5, '*', [['-', 10], '**', 2]]]
5 and not 8     <=>  [[5, 'and', ['not', 8]]]
5 and -8        <=>  [[5, 'and', ['-', 8]]]
1 ** -2         <=>  [[1, '**', -2]]
-1 ** 2         <=>  [['-', [1, '**', 2]]]
```

---

Doc for `pyparsing_common` with [other predefined expressions](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html#pyparsing.pyparsing_common)

Comment: But that gives an unusual interpretation for `5 * -10 ** 2` which evaluates to -500 (at least in Python, and many other languages with an exponentiation operator).

Comment: your parser gives result `5 * (-10 ** 2)` similar to `5 * 10 ** -2` which gives `5 * (10 ** -2)` and `5 * 10 ** (-2)` which gives `5 * (10 ** (-2))`. Only Python has different order of operators so it gives different value.

Comment: I can get `-500` when I keep `**` before `-` but I use `integer = pyparsing.pyparsing_common.signed_integer` - see new code in answer.

Comment: @rici is correct, I would like to maintain the co rrect precedence of operators for that reason. With your change `5 * -10 ** 2` will be `['5', '*', [['-', '10'], '**', '2']]` rather than `['5', '*', ['-', ['10', '**', '2']]]`

Comment: Very interesting, your new answer has indeed fixed my issue.

Comment: I found doc with [other predefined expressions](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing_common-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for bringing back such an old subject but I'm writing a very similar parser for my project which mix Boolean logic and mathematical operator and I ended up with such a similar code that it seemed appropriate.

Since the parser given here encounter the same issue than mine, I'm going to use it to show my problem.

I can't make it parse "$true == not $false", and basically, any "not" after a comparaison won't work without parenthesis.

```
$true == $false        <=>  [['$true', '==', '$false']]
$true == not $false    <=>  ['$true']
$true == (not $false)  <=>  [['$true', '==', ['not', '$false']]]
```

As you can see without the "not" or with parenthesis, it parse fine, but with a simple "not" it seems to ignore everything after the "=="

What kind of fix it is to move the "not" operator first in the infix_notation (previously operatorPrecedence). Then I got those results:

```
$true == not $false    <=>  [['$true', '==', ['not', '$false']]]
$true == (not $false)  <=>  [['$true', '==', ['not', '$false']]]
```

Which are greats, but of course it broke operator precedence for things like "$true and not 10 == 9" which I'd like to be parse "$true and not (10 == 9)" like in python and instead parse like that:

```
$true and not 10 == 9  <=>  [['$true', 'and', [['not', 10], '==', 9]]]
```

I was wondering if you encounters those use case in the implementation of your parser and have found a way around them.